# showing non Umbraco View, error "HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found"

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-4, umbraco, umbraco7, umbraco-mvc

In MVC 4 application I have Nuget Umbraco CMS 7.

I need to keep a non-Umbraco/ custom controller with view. I have created an MVC controller named `Users` which has an action named `Index`. I have updated `umbracoReservedUrls` in web.config as below:

```
<add key="umbracoReservedUrls" value="~/config/splashes/booting.aspx,~/install/default.aspx,~/config/splashes/noNodes.aspx,~/VSEnterpriseHelper.axd,~/Users/Index" />
```

Below is my controller code:

```
 public class UsersController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Users/

        public ActionResult Index(User model)
        {
            return View(model);
        }

    }
```

My view markup is as below:

```
@model Common.Model.User

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>
```

Issue:
On running if I navigate to `http://localhost:56512/users/index`, control do not come to controller and in browser I got 404 error as detailed below:

```
HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.
```

Can you please guide how to fix this and navigate to non Umbraco views and controllers ?

Answer (score -1):

Put the controllerpath in `umbracoReservedPaths` instead of `UmbracoReservedUrls`.

Or consider to wrap your controller in a RenderMvcController, surface controller, partial view, ...

Comment: Thanks @dampee, my controller 'UsersController' is in default controlelrs folder and view 'Index' is in view/Users/Index. Can you please guide how I should configure it ? Is it same as I mentioned above ?

Comment: my controller is located in default controllers folder. I did   <add key="umbracoReservedPaths" value="~/umbraco,~/install/,~/Controllers/" /> but it did not work.

Comment: Are you sure your controller is compiled?  If you are using a website (in webmatrix e.g.), it's easier to move it to App_Code.